# GLFW library not found

Tags: python, macos, glfw

Я работаю на операционной системе MacOs. Пытаюсь запустить код на python. Я использую билиотеку p5. Она установлена:

```
(base) bash-3.2$ pip install p5
Requirement already satisfied: p5 in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: vispy in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from p5) (0.6.4)
Requirement already satisfied: triangle in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from p5) (20200424)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from p5) (1.16.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from p5) (5.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: glfw in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from p5) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: freetype-py in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from vispy->p5) (2.2.0)
```

Запускаю код:

```
RuntimeError: Could not import backend "Glfw":
GLFW library not found
```

Если я устанавливаю отдельно glfw, то:

```
pip install glfw
Requirement already satisfied: glfw in /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.12.0)
```

Почему не работает, и как сделать чтобы работало?

Comment: Приведите код ваш :)

Comment: А какая разрядность питона 32 или 64? Тут https://pypi.org/project/glfw/ написано: `The GLFW shared library for 64-bit is included in the Python wheels for macOS.`

Comment: @gil9red вроде 64

Comment: @dIm0n Вы уверены?

Comment: @ДарьяВысоцкая ну да, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему

Comment: @dIm0n Ну он большой